# Use pouchdb promise polifil

Tags: promise, pouchdb

I'm using pouchdb as a library in a tiddlywiky project. It provides a common js compatible environment, so I can just require it. 
My project is targeted to several  browsers so I can't  expect  promises to be available as default. Since pouchdb uses promises extensively I tough that it will be simpler to use promises  in the rest of my code. I know that pouch includes a promise polifil, so here is my question :
Is that polifil available from outside? Can I use it? How?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use PouchDB's promise polyfill by using `pouchdb-promise`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-promise

If you are using npm, then it's just `require('pouchdb-promise')`. Otherwise, you can get it from wzrd.in: https://wzrd.in/standalone/pouchdb-promise

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was not talking about including another dependency. I am using pouch at the browser, and I want to re-utilize the promise library that is bundled into it. How is your suggestion different from including any other promise polyfill ?